# didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I want to get the current location, but instead I get an error.

This is a snippet of my view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    // I would get the latest location here
    // but this method never gets called
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
}
```

I'm expecting the delegate method `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` to get called, but instead, only `locationManager:didFailWithError:` gets called, and prints this:

```
didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

Comment: You can use a google api as an alternative. Refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40670608/2033377

Comment: goto simulator -> features -> location -> `Apple`. if you have that set to `none` it won't work and throw this error., I did this on accident

Answer (score 111, accepted):

1. Check that you actually have a valid WiFi and 3G connection

   ...if you do, then:
2. Go to settings and reset your location services
3. Reset your network settings

This should take care of that issue. It is device/network related not app related. It's annoying especially if your app is dependent on location services and the device is WiFi only and people give negative ratings on the AppStore... Pardon me, I'm getting a bit emotional there.

Comment: As far as I know GPS doesn't need either internet or wifi connection.It's just a receiver if it is in accessible location with 2 or 3 of GPS satellites we can get the geo location coordinates.Then why does the error come if there is no internet or wifi connection?

Comment: One upvote for pointing out reseting location services and network settings

Comment: You shouldn't have to go through these steps. Simply ignore this error and wait for more updates. See my answer below or view the docs at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/cllocationmanagerdelegate_protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:

Comment: That "bug" drove me crazy.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, while playing with MapKit & CoreLocation,  on my device (iPhone 5S, iOS 8.1.3). I was unable to get a location, and got the same error again & again (in spite of a good mobile network signal). Until I switched the WiFi On, and everything was fixed! Weird... Thanks !

Comment: This has solved my issue...Thank you, 1. I have rewetted contents and settings.

Comment: 2. Removed data from derived data. 3. Restarted the Xcode, and Simulator and worked for me like a charm, thanks

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H iPads don't have actual GPS hardware. They use a database of wifi MAC addresses to determine your location.

Comment: @whoKnows - They have GPS receiver builtin.. assisted GPS.. It uses Wifi signal and or Cellular towers to triagulate position..3G/LTE iPad has a real GPS built-in

Comment: @MeM I never would have caught that. You just saved me HOURS.

Comment: So basically Xcode is telling me about an error and the right thing to do is ignore it completely? Why am I not surprised...

Answer (score 162):

If you are using the simulator:

1. Press `command + shift + ,` in Xcode to open the scheme editor
2. Select the Run scheme
3. Go to the Options tab
4. Check ✅ `Allow Location Simulation`
5. Select a Default Location in the dropdown

Selecting `None` as your Default Location may have caused the problem.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, I've been chasing this for weeks. My app kept forcing my iPad or iPhone to the London, England location, and I could not figure out why. I turned that option off and the problem is gone.Maybe it was having a hiccup grabbing the location and then going off and changing the location to the one on the Scheme.

Comment: Worked for me, but I also had to do `iOS Simulator` > `Reset Content and Settings...`

Comment: Nailed it for me.

Answer (score 27):

Simply ignore this error and wait for more updates or a different error.

The docs for the location manager say that this error is temporary. It's letting you know that it failed to immediately retrieve a location, but it continues to try. "In such a situation, you can simply ignore the error and wait for a new event." Which is a really boneheaded way to use a method named `locationManager:didFailWithError:` - Thanks Apple!

[`Apple Documentation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/corelocation/reference/cllocationmanagerdelegate_protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:)

Answer (score 19):

Try restarting the simulator (assuming that's what you're using).

After trying everything else this worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

A restart of the simulator didn't work for me.

> I had to clear everything via `"iOS Simulator" >> "Reset Content and
>   Settings...`.

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this error on the simulator. Clicking the location button in the debugging panel and setting a location fixed the issue for me. (Ensure that the button is blue)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem.   I believe the possible explanations / fixes are covered [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1409141/35794).

Answer (score 5):

Changing the "Location" on the simulator worked for me.

> Debug > Location > (Mine was checked None instead of City Bicycle Ride
>   e.g.)

Answer (score 5):

> 1. In the simulator go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy
> 2. Quit simulator and run app again

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Simulator, make sure the scheme allows location, and you picked a default location.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using the simulator, you can to `Debug -> Location` and set a location.

If you have none selected you will have this error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a `custom location` make sure you have the long and lat the correct way, i had it reversed and wasted 3 hours before i realised...

Comment: Ame here I have also wasted 2 hours , set the Latitude and Longitude in correct positions.

Answer (score 3):

I have see the problem before,there is a way to solve it,but it can only work one time.If you want to run the project again and you need to repeat the solution each time.

> 1.In Xcode,Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme,then cancel the "Allow Location Simulator".
>
> 2.To the iOS Simulator and reset Content and Setting.
>
> 3.Again to the Xcode,repeat the first step.
>
> 4.To the iOS Simulator and reset. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Issues like this can be resolved by setting location as "`Apple`". At least it works for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I have reseted contents and settings.
> 2. Removed data from derived data.
> 3. Restarted the Xcode, and Simulator and worked for me.

from the answer of @Mem and many others thanks

Answer (score 1):

For returned devs :) Just select "`Debug->Location->Freeway Drive`" from the Simulator menu. If still problem then try after doing "Simulator->Reset Content and Settings" form the simulator menu. This helped me once with the same issue. Some time simulator location is set to "`Custom location`" due to which its not detecting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try in device. Sometimes simulator fails to take your location.

Answer (score 0):

Go to home in simulator

home ->Settings ->Privacy ->Locations -> select the app and choose always

Answer (score 0):

when adding permission Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description in the info.plist it was solved for me