# Error while getting core location : (null)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am unable to get my current location on device. It shows first some times correctly but third time it fails and shows this message:

```
Error while getting core location : (null)
```

My code is:

```
CLLocationManager *manager;
manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;
    manager.delegate = self;//or whatever class you have for managing location
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"in update location");
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error while getting core location : %@",[error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

Output is:

```
2013-07-03 18:32:33.146 CLLocationUpdate[6084:907] in update location
2013-07-03 18:32:33.200 CLLocationUpdate[6084:907] in update location
2013-07-03 18:32:33.517 CLLocationUpdate[6084:907] in update location
2013-07-03 18:32:34.073 CLLocationUpdate[6084:907] in update location
2013-07-03 18:32:50.903 CLLocationUpdate[6084:907] Error while getting core location : (null)
```

Help please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you print error.localizedDescription instead?

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

Answer (score 0):

That kind of error (The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)) can be due to a lot of reasons.

I found a couple of links that talk about the problem, have you checked them?

[Location Manager Error : (KCLErrorDomain error 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409141/location-manager-error-kclerrordomain-error-0)
[didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldnt-be)

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation:

```
Configuration of your location manager object must always occur on a thread with 
an active run loop, such as your application’s main thread.
```

Comment: Then how can i resolve this issue. FYI this is working perfect in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the settings of location services, Wifi and network operator. Sometimes it occurs due to invalid settings of resources which provide the location of device.