# CLLocationManager doesn't get location

Tags: objective-c, ios7, core-location

I'm Using CLLocationManager to get the current location of the device and i tried to get the `location` property in order to get the longitude and latitude as follows:

```
-(void)getCurrentLocation{
CLLocationManager *manager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];;
manager.delegate=self;
manager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.currentLocation=manager.location;
NSLog(@"Current Lat :%f",self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"Current Long :%f",self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);

[manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Given that:

```
self.currentLocation is a property inside my class (Which is the CLLocationManagerDelegate) as follows:
```

.h

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) CLLocation *currentLocation;
```

and the getter in the .m is as follows:

```
-(CLLocation *)currentLocation{
if (!_currentLocation) {
    _currentLocation=[[CLLocation alloc]init ];
}
return _currentLocation;

}
```

I forget to say that i have implemented the `didUpdateToLocation` Method as follows:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation");
CLLocation *loc=newLocation;
if (loc!=nil) {
    self.currentLocation=loc;

}  

}
```

I also tried to put this statement after the `startUpdateLocation` call:

```
    self.currentLocation=manager.location;
```

the problem is that when i call the previous function `getCurrentLocation` the two NSLogs inside it prints `0.000000` which means that `manager.location` isn't working and the weird thing is that the first NSLog inside `didUpdateToLocation` doesn't printed , thanks in advance

Comment: You should implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` methods (notably, `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`) and wait until you get called there. You should view this process of starting location manager and waiting for responses as an asynchronous process.

Comment: Please note that didUpdateToLocation is deprecated as of iOS 6.0! Use didUpdateLocations as in my example instead.

Your problem is that your delegate method is not called until a later point in time. Could be 10 ms, or a few seconds. Depends on the GPS signal etc.

Try and move your NSLog calls to the delegate method as implemented in my exmaple below.

Answer (score 2):

You can't just read the location from the CLLocationManager. It needs to update its location before that property is assigned:

```
The value of this property is nil if no location data has ever been retrieved.
```

[CLLocationManager SDK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#jumpTo_10)

You must implement the delegate method [locationManager:didUpdateLocations:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#jumpTo_12)

And when that is called you can read the `location` property, or look at the `locations` argument:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    self.currentLocation = [locations firstObject];

    NSLog(@"Current Lat :%f",self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
    NSLog(@"Current Long :%f",self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation]
}
```

You can call `[manager stopUpdatingLocation]` when you get the first call, so it doesn't keep running.

Comment: @JavaPlayer Your problem is still that you're trying to read the location before it has been retrieved from the GPS. And furthermore, you're using a deprecated delegate method, as explained in my comment above.

Try to implement my delegate method above and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that and it's working well on simulator but it's not working on the device (the didUpdateLocations method isn't called !!) although i'm turning on the location service of the device

Comment: Try to implement locationManager:didFailWithError: and see if there are any errors. If it works in th simulator, and not on the device something must be going wrong.

Comment: locationManager:didFailWithError: also doesn't working on device !!

Comment: Are you sure location services are enabled on the device? Try to call `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` and `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` - and see if they return `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` and `YES` respectively.

Comment: Error:Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)", didFailWithError is called but i didn't note that (as it's executed after long time) and the previous error is raised

Comment: Give me some context please. Device? OS version? On wifi? This error seems specific to the simulator.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldnt-be