# Reset settings on iPhone now device doesn't show in Xcode to run application

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, core-location

I was having an issue with Core Location in my app so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldn-t-be) advice (the selected answer) and reset my network and location settings on my device. Now that I've done that, my device isn't showing up as an option to build and run the app in the top left corner of Xcode. It just says "iPhone" when it should say "Aaron's iPhone 4S" which is what I named the device I'm testing on. What happened and how do I add it back in?

I am using Xcode 6.3.2 and an iPhone 4S with 8.3

Here is a screenshot of the Devices window:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure, you have reset only Network settings? It seems you have reset the device, connect with itunes to setup the device again. Plus check from XCode->Window->Devices whether it is listing your device or, not, or it is asking for any action.

Comment: @iphonic On my iPhone I only went to Settings->General->Reset->"Reset Network Settings" and "Reset Location & Privacy" I updated my question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just says "iPhone" because name of your iPhone is "iPhone". So your iPhone is in list of devices, I think you can build and run the application as normal. Check setting of your iPhone to make sure the name of device.