# Can't get my external device's location in Xcode

Tags: xcode, location

I would like to get my iPad's location in Xcode. When I simulate the location to... for example Tokyo, it works, gives me latitude and longitude.

But I want my iPad's location (so, my home), so I turned off location simulation, reset the location settings on my device, allowed the app to locate me, and I get this error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

My location service is on and allowed for my app. I don't get why this isn't working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldn-t-be       Using this article, have you confirmed that your iPad is on wifi or 3g?

Comment: My iPad is connected to my WiFi, like my Mac. They use the same WiFi.