# Swift ios error in getting location?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I am using [INTULocationManager](https://github.com/intuit/LocationManager) (ios, swift) library for getting location in my app, and I often get error in getting location. The error which appears in log is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldn-t-be/6768989). The real issue is **other apps like Uber are able to get current location**.

Below is my code for getting location:

```
    var locMgr: INTULocationManager = INTULocationManager.sharedInstance()

    locMgr.requestLocationWithDesiredAccuracy(INTULocationAccuracy.Block,        
      timeout: timeInterval,
      delayUntilAuthorized: true,
      block: {(currentLoc: CLLocation!, achievedAccuracy: INTULocationAccuracy, status: INTULocationStatus) -> Void in

            if status == INTULocationStatus.Success {
               // got location successfully
            } else {
               // error, this happens often
            }
    })
```

Edit: I was able to solve it by constantly hitting the same request again in the failure block for upto 10 times. It is working much better now.

Comment: Are you using simulator or real device?

Comment: @redent84 I am using real device..

Comment: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"? I'm getting the same problem with Swift 2.1

Comment: Use CLLocationManager instead and see if this has the same issue. If not, add an issue to the github page.