# Location Manger Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager

While running my code into device, I'm not able to getting device current location.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

method called. I'm not able to getting device locations while device is in motion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldn-t-be)

Comment: how can you register the location manager ?

Comment: please provide your code so we can help you. without code we are unable to find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8 ownwards by default location services are desabled for a new app you create.So to enable it go to settings->privacy->location services and choose your app from it and make it "always" under allow location services.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**1.**  You have to set default location:

```
Debug -> Location
```

**2.**  you have to clear all data using

```
 "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and
  Settings....
```

**3.**

Then clean the project and run the project.. i hope it will work..:)