# Error while updating location The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cllocationmanager

I am getting this error:

> Error while updating location The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

My problem is that this error shows almost every time I run the simulator and it keeps showing me that error a whole time that simulator runs (every time I present viewController with a map it shows me this error).The weirdest thing is that sometimes this error is nil and everything is fine. On an actual device it works fine, but when I want to try something with  location (on simulator) I have to restart the simulator about 7 times until it works.

This is Info.plist:

[image]

My Location is custom:

[image]

This is my code:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: "We were unable to find your location", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("Error...")
    }
```

My question is why it works only sometimes? 
Thank you :)

Comment: You can check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032976/didfailwitherror-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-the-operation-couldn-t-be

Comment: I have already seen that question and I could not find the solution :/

Comment: Then select simulator menu>debug>location>set custom or select any 0r check internet connection

Comment: My internet connection should be fine (I am sitting like 2 meters from my router and the internet is fast).

Answer (score 5):

Please, check this and let me know. Do it on simulator and then try.
[image]

Updated:

I have just tried, it's working fine same error comes when I assigned location as **NONE**.
Working Code

```
import CoreLocation
Conform CLLocationManagerDelegate
Create var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
Plist - NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription add.

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("locations = \(locations)")
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry!", message: "We were unable to find your location", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("Error...")
}
```

I am getting location properly using above code and if I did not put the Location for Simulator then getting following error:

**Error while updating location The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)**

When it runs correctly:
**locations = [<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/14/16, 2:34:46 PM Pakistan Standard Time]**

Comment: Updated my xcode to xcode8 and error is gone :) , but thank you +1

Answer (score 2):

For Xcode 11.5, this menu was moved to (*Simulator > Features > Location*)!
Also, reinstall the app after selecting a simulated location.

[image]

The second place to check is (*Xcode > Debug > Simulate Location*). When "Custom location" selected in Simulator.

[image]