# iphone : CLLocation deletgate method called randomly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I am using `CLLocationManager` to grab the location.Though `I have GPS settings working on my device`, it shows the status popup randomly which is defined in `didFailWithError`

Error I am getting is,

```
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

-(void) startGettingCurrentLocation {

    CLLocationManager *locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [locatingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];

    UIAlertView *statusAlert;

    statusAlert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"In order to use this application properly, you need to allow use of the GPS." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [statusAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [statusAlert show];

    //Set Default Coordinates it app not able to get location
    if (mainDelegate.currentLatitude == nil) {
        mainDelegate.currentLatitude = @"28.6317021";
    }

    if (mainDelegate.currentLongitude == nil) {
        mainDelegate.currentLongitude = @"-81.423110";
    }
}
```

Comment: please have a look at this http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/

Comment: how you are calling that delegate ?

Comment: i asked whether you placed cllocationmanager.delegate=self in viewdidload?

Comment: why you want to show alert if you are updating everytime ? instead you can remove alert right?

Comment: Edited the question,please take a look

Comment: can you tell whether you are updating everytime or you are updating only one time at start of app ?

Comment: means you are using [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; anywhere ? or you are allowing to update everytime

Comment: okay then post the error you are getting?

Comment: check this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409141/location-manager-error-kclerrordomain-error-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find out whats the error

```
if([[error code] isEqualTo: kCLErrorLocationUnknown])
{
   The location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now.
}
```

other error codes

```
kCLErrorLocationUnknown

The location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now.

kCLErrorDenied

Access to the location service was denied by the user.

kCLErrorNetwork

The network was unavailable or a network error occurred.

kCLErrorHeadingFailure

The heading could not be determined.

kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied

Access to the region monitoring service was denied by the user.

kCLErrorRegionMonitoringFailure

A registered region cannot be monitored.

kCLErrorRegionMonitoringSetupDelayed

Core Location could not initialize the region monitoring feature immediately.
```

Comment: @Heena it won't work on simulator. There are restrictions, biggest one being the hardware.

Comment: find this SO que.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409141/location-manager-error-kclerrordomain-error-0