# Get user location in a simple ViewController in iOS 7 (didUpdateLocation)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

How can I get the user Location in a simple ViewController in iOS 7?
I have tried in this way, but on debugging I saw that `didUpdateLocation` method isn't called:

In MyViewController.h:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;   
}
```

In MyViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    //locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"NewLocation %f %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed %ld",(long)[error code]);

}
```

`didUpdateLocations` isn't called, but is called `didFailWithError` printing in log: "Failed 0". Please help me!

Comment: Have you checked `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` and `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]`?

Comment: Yes
[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] is 1 and
[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] is 3

Comment: According to `CLError.h` error code 0 is `kCLErrorLocationUnknown`. Are you running this on a device or in the simulator?

Comment: The problem was the simulator that once time doesn't simulate location, once time simulate location!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly check that you actually have a valid WiFi and 3G connection

then

1) go to settings and reset your location services

2) reset your network settings

Also check is the default location set if its in a simulator. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15500603/2869784) link will show that.

Answer (score 1):

CLLocation manager says

```
kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0, // User has not yet made a choice with regards to this application
kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,        // This application is not authorized to use location services.  Due
                                         // to active restrictions on location services, the user cannot change
                                         // this status, and may not have personally denied authorization
kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,            // User has explicitly denied authorization for this application, or
                                         // location services are disabled in Settings
kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized         // User has authorized this application to use location services
```

In your case `CLAuthorizationStatus  0` means you not allow app to access location services.

Comment: CLAuthorizationStatus in my case is 3!