# Testing a fake current location on iOS Simulater is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, ios-simulator

I have been trying to fake my location in the iOS simulator but the methods I have been reading about are not working. I have used the debugger to set my fake location, and have made a custom location in Debug->Location->Custom Location, yet I still log 0.000 0.000 for lat and long. 
I'm using this code to find current location.

```
- (IBAction)currentLocationButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //Search for pubs and bars in current location.
    //Push to tableViewController
    NSLog(@"current location Pressed.");

    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // Best accuracy
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self deviceLocation]);
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Latitude: %f Longitude: %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    }
}

- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
```

The delegate is set and I am requesting authorization.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchLocationTextField.delegate = self;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];  // For foreground access
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; // For background access

}
```

Comment: While running simulator, you can also simulate current location from xcode: 'Debug' -> 'Simulate Location' . Have you tried with that?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Didn't work. @AsifAsif

Comment: I think stubbing the current location would make more sense in this sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set locationManager delegate to after allocating it.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` delegate method is deprecated, use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` instead.

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Latitude: %f Longitude: %f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems to make more sense, but
NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", [locations lastObject]);
wont even log to the console.

Comment: Even after update, currentLocation is not logged to the console.
it seems as though the method isnt even getting called.

Comment: Also, you need to set delegate after allocating the locationManager, not the other way. Answer updated.

Comment: I thought that'd be it. Still not getting logged to the console.

Comment: do you have a device to test on? The location delegate does not always get fired in simulator. I am used to this behavior since Xcode 5.

Comment: No, I can only use the simulator right now. You're saying you think its just a bug? I guess for now I will just stub the current location.

Comment: btw, I noticed the call to both `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and `requestAlwaysAuthorization`. Have you added the keys `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the info.plist?

Comment: I just did. I got this error.
2014-10-18 16:59:48.430 YelpTest2[9899:685126] Location manager failed to find loction with error:Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: related solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409141/location-manager-error-kclerrordomain-error-0