# iOS 8 - Can't get current location, Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, ios-simulator, cllocationmanager

I've problem with getting my current location. I still getting error:

```
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

I already did everything that I found here:

Reset content and settings in iOS Simulator (map application in simulator shows correct location).

In Xcode at Product>Scheme>Edit I unmarked Allow Location Simulation (when I mark it,It simulate e.g. London).

I have added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to Info.plist file in my project (App asks for Location permissions and I can see them in Settings in iOS simulator).

I have Wi-Fi connection turned on (like I said location services works fine in Safari, Maps or even Maps in iOS Simulator).

```
-(void)viewDidLoad    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

       self.locationManager.delegate = self;
       if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){
           NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
           if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined && ([self.locationManager    respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {

               if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
                   [self.locationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
               } else {
                   NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or    NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
               }
           }
       }
       [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
       [self.FirstMap setShowsUserLocation:YES];    }

   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error    {
       NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
       UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [errorAlert show];    }
```

Is there something that i forgot about?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543754/ios-9-error-domain-kclerrordomain-code-0-null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess maybe you need to read this thread first as it's largely overlapped.

[Location Manager Error : (KCLErrorDomain error 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409141/location-manager-error-kclerrordomain-error-0)

But anyway, I tested your code and got the same error as you reported. Then I change the simulation configuration. To be specific, in the simulator, I clicked Debug -> Location -> Custom Location... and enter a coordinate, and I can periodically receive location events (at a speed of every sample per second.) So  maybe the problem is not from the code but from the simulator itself. Hope my answer helps.

**UPDATE**

I guess I misunderstood your question. What you want is to "automatically" get your current location in simulator. I'm afraid there's no such feature in xcode, instead, you need to use "add gpx file to project", which is even more work than using customized location. But I mean, if you've successfully got correct locations, why it bothers you to get the correct current location from the simulator, or alternative, maybe you can test on phone?

Comment: Like I said when I specify location e.g. London it shows correctly. Location services in map application in simulator also works(So simulator gets location).

Comment: Ouh, I didn't know that I can't get current location in iOS Simulator. I thought that if map application on Simulator shows correctly(same as Map app in Mac) there is a way to show that. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 8 you have to first take the permission from the user to access the location you cannot access the local as in iOS 7

```
if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        if self.manager.respondsToSelector("requestWhenInUseAuthorization") {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        } else {
            startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

for more take help from this link http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

Answer (score 1):

Check Internet connection.
if connection is ok then
First Go to Xcode log bar and set "Dont simulate location". Then select simulator menu>debug>location>set custom or select any.