# My location request view isn't working for some but I don't know where's my mistake?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-location

My app has been refused for the second time because of the location request and for some time I didn't know why. Some nice people on SO told me it was probably because I offer no other option than the location request to continue in the app. But fortunately, the App Store verification team confirmed to me it was simply because when they tap on the "Allow location" button nothing happens.

I don't see where my mistake is because on my side everything goes very well whether on a physical device or in the simulator.

Do you see anything? Could you test this minimal reproducible example in Xcode and tell me what's going on for you?

```
// BootcampApp.swift

import SwiftUI

@main
struct BootcampApp: App {
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManager()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(locationManager)
        }
    }
}
```

```
// ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var locationManager: LocationManager

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let userLocation = locationManager.userLocation, let cityName = locationManager.cityName {
                HomeView(userLocation: userLocation, cityName: cityName)
            } else {
                WelcomeView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// HomeView.swift

import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct HomeView: View {
    let userLocation: CLLocation
    let cityName: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}
```

```
// WelcomeView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct WelcomeView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var locationManager: LocationManager

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Allow location", action: { locationManager.requestLocation() })
        }
    }
}
```

```
// LocationManager.swift

import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var userLocation: CLLocation?
    @Published var cityName: String?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.distanceFilter = 100
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func requestLocation() {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        userLocation = location
        reverseGeocode(location)
    }

    func reverseGeocode(_ location: CLLocation) {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
            guard let placemark = placemarks?.first else { return }
            self.cityName = placemark.locality
        }
    }
}
```

```
// Info.plist

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description => "The app needs your location."
```

Thanks, in advance!

**EDIT**

I added this function into the `LocationManager`:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Location manager failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

And now I get this error when the app launches: "Location manager failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)".

Here's the error itself: "Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)".

So, I think this is the error that posed problem since the beginning.

Comment: LocationManager Is doing too much, best break it up into separate Authorization, location updates and geocoding. That way if location becomes unauthorized you can hide the Views and the other objects will be deinit.

Comment: Might be an issue with **why** the app needs the users location. In your Info.plist you don't offer an an explanation to why the app needs the users location or how it's used. They may take issue with you seemingly using users location for no good reason.

Comment: @TimD Actually, in my real project, I use a real explanation but here I just wrote `The app needs your location` to be quick.

Comment: I actually discovered a silent error: `The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)`.

Comment: @burnsi I edited the post. The error appears at the launch of the app. It's a very new error as I check only now if there's an error with a new func. Strangely, the error has no impact on the app on developer mode.

Comment: please print the error itself and add the output to the question.

Comment: @burnsi Done. It's actually quite the same result as `localizedDescription`.

Comment: The problem might come from `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` because when it's commented the error isn't displayed but the location request don't works as well.

Comment: Are you aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350245/the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-kclerrordomain-error-1)

Comment: @burnsi I actually discovered the problem and found the solution yesterday. If you look at the code twice, it's very obvious. I'll post the solution later. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling `startUpdatingLocation` too soon before you have authorized. It's best to separate authorization from location updates. Do this with an `AuthorizationView` and `AuthorizationManager` with its own instance of `CLLocationManager` that only performs and monitors authorization. Then only show the `LocationView` when authorized and hide it again when non authorized.