# Cordova geoLocation plugin in iOS not working fine

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, geolocation

Now I am using cordova application app **for getting current latitude and longitude** so I have used cordova `geolocation plugin` for both iOS and android.

This plugin I have installed in CLI

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

and I have  used the same codes used in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

But its worked fine in android and iOS simulator (custom location) but in my iPad and iPhone its don't work ...I don't know why please tell anyone why some times its showing error like code:2, message:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.) & code:3 error....

Comment: What is the version of your iPhone and iPad device?

Comment: iOS 8.3 and iPhone 8.4

Comment: and i have xcode 6.4 latest version..

Comment: Can you post your related code and error what you are getting?

Comment: this is the messae i getting ..The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)  and sometimes my geolocation (latitude and Longitude) was totally different when i compared to android..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the Geolocation plugin (but no  changes) to your config.xml, you will find the following in your compiled app's Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>

<string></string>
```

The result of which is that on a geolocation call, the user is prompted with

Allow "App Name" to access your location while you use the app?

If in addition to the plugin you add the following to your config.xml:

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="true">

        <string>WE RE LIKE TOTALLY TRACKING YOU OMG</string>

</gap:config-file>
```

you will find the following in your compiled app's Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>

<string>WE RE LIKE TOTALLY TRACKING YOU OMG</string>
```

and the result will be that on a geolocation call, the user is prompted with

Allow "App Name" to access your location even when you are not using the app? WE RE LIKE TOTALLY TRACKING YOU OMG

After clicking allow in both scenarios, geolocation calls were successful

Comment: i already paste this key in my .plist and i click allow to access the geolocation but seems the same result.. i need only think where2 i want to paste <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="true">

        <string>WE RE LIKE TOTALLY TRACKING YOU OMG</string>

</gap:config-file>

Comment: in which config.xml outer the project or inside the staging folder.

Comment: check in your setting for the install app allows location update or not ?

Comment: check here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/r0.3.10/plugin.xml#L82

Comment: <config-file target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
            <string></string>
        </config-file>   This line is already in geolocation plugin.xml..

Comment: iOS version you are using in you iPhone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409141/location-manager-error-kclerrordomain-error-0 check here and reset your network connection

Comment: i am using iPad mini (Model A1432) it has iOS 7.1.2