# Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" in any ios device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5

I am run in my application for finding a current location but first time return right lat long with there dependent locality but when they didUpdateLocations that time goes to didFailWithError and return **Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"**. I have try diffrent diffrent solution like

1. Reset Content and Settings
2. In Xcode,Product -> Scheme -> Edit
   Scheme,then cancel the "Allow Location Simulator"and To the iOS
   Simulator and reset Content and Setting and Again to the
   Xcode,repeat the first step.and To the iOS Simulator and reset.

but none of that work

my code for this is here:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", [locations lastObject]);
CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];


if (currentLocation != nil)
{
    self.lblLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.12f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    self.lblLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.12f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
}


NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");


[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
        placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        NSString *geoMapItem = placemark.description;
        NSRange start = [geoMapItem rangeOfString:@"dependentLocality"];

        NSRange end = [geoMapItem rangeOfString:@")" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(start.location, 1000)];
        NSString *dataString = [geoMapItem substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location, end.location - start.location + end.length)];
        dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];
        dataString = [dataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

        start = [dataString rangeOfString:@"("];
        end = [dataString rangeOfString:@")"];
        NSLog(@"datastring===>%@",dataString);
        lblAddress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                        dataString,
                        placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                        placemark.administrativeArea,
                        placemark.country];
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
    }
} ];}
```

after update location first time goes to error block

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"didFailWithError%@",error);
UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[errorAlert show];}
```

and get this error didFailWithErrorError Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: Are you running it on simulator?

Comment: Did you check out this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409141/location-manager-error-kclerrordomain-error-0

Comment: no i am trying on ipad,iphone5s,iphone6.

Comment: @Dominic I see your Suggestion but I am Not Satisfy Can you Please provide me more ..

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar I am Try in different different ios Devices but nothing change

Comment: @BhumeshPurohit there isn't much more to add. If you are not satisfied with the answer on SO that already explains some answers then you could explain why your problem is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello Guys I found The Solutions of My own question. 
Some minor mistake done by me. I am check currentLocation != nil every time so, it's update location but current location Lat Long is not set.

```
//if (currentLocation != nil)
//{
    self.lblLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.12f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    self.lblLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.12f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
//}
```

now it's Run Properly.